# maven 2 & 5.4.5: info.magnolia.test.RepositoryTestCase don't work anymore

Tags: unit-testing, content-management-system, magnolia

I am using some test cases that extend info.magnolia.test.RepositoryTestCase and only with maven 2 and the latest 5.4.5 version those tests fail:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Resource not found: target/repositories.xml
at info.magnolia.test.RepositoryTestCase.getRepositoryConfigFileStream(RepositoryTestCase.java:167)
at info.magnolia.test.RepositoryTestCase.extractConfigFilesForTests(RepositoryTestCase.java:150)
at info.magnolia.test.RepositoryTestCase.startRepository(RepositoryTestCase.java:136)
at info.magnolia.test.RepositoryTestCase.setUp(RepositoryTestCase.java:99)
....
```

Everything is okay with either Maven 3 or Magnolia 5.4.4

Do you have any clue on how to solve this?

Maven info:

```
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (rdebian-14)
Java version: 1.8.0_74
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux" version: "3.13.0-55-generic" arch: "amd64" Family: "unix"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is strongly suggested to use Maven-3 (precisely 3.2.3) when you are using Magnolia. I would strongly suggest you to upgrade Maven-2 since its already end of live.

More information can be found on
https://wiki.magnolia-cms.com/display/DEV/Maven+setup